# Query table and compare with another query (if exist, show in result)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is table test

```
ID          order_no      film_type   process   line
100         RXQFW40-1       FW          SL      HL21
101         RXQFW46-1-1     EXFW        EX      HE15
103         RXQFW49-1       FW          SL      HL21
173         RXQFW49-1-1     EXFW        EX      HE15
107         RXQFW4E-1       FW          SL      HL21
115         RXQFW4E-1       FW          SL      HL21
169         RXQFW4E-1-1     EXFW        EX      HE13
168         RXQFW4E-1-1     EXFW        EX      HE13
104         RXQFW4K-1       FW          SL      HL21
172         RXQFW4K-1-1     EXFW        EX      HE15
```

First, I want to filter process='SL' and get the first 7 character of order_no.

```
Select distinct substring(order_no,1,7) where process='SL' from test
```

Next

If the result meets

```
Select distinct substring(order_no,1,7) where process='EX' from test
```

That will be the output:

```
order_no
RXQFW49-1 
RXQFW4E-1 
RXQFW4K-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use a `WHERE EXISTS` like below by combining both the queries

```
Select distinct substring(order_no,1,7) 
from test t
where process='EX' 
and EXISTS ( Select 1 from test 
where process='SL' 
and substring(t.order_no,1,7) = substring(order_no,1,7));
```

Answer (score 1):

A different aproach to `EXISTS` you can `JOIN` using the `substring` result. And is easier to read.

And looks like the result is always the `SL.order_no` so no need apply another substring there.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0408a/4)

```
SELECT DISTINCT SL.order_no
FROM test SL
inner join test EX
   on  substring(SL.order_no,1,7) = substring(EX.order_no,1,7)
WHERE SL.process  = 'SL'
AND   EX.process  = 'EX'
```

Answer (score 0):

join them:

```
select distinct sl.ord from 
( Select distinct substring(order_no,1,7) ord where process='SL' from test ) sl
,( Select distinct substring(order_no,1,7) ord where process='EX' from test ) ex
where sl.ord = ex.ord
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ?

```
Select t.ord
from test t 
where process = 'SL' 
   AND
   exists (select * from test t2 where left(t.order_no,7) = left(t2.order,7) AND process = 'EX')
```